# Good design to Insert multiple records

Tags: jpa, bulkinsert

I am working on a program that read from a file and insert line by line into Oracle 11g database using JTA/EclipseLink 2.3.x JPA with container managed transaction.

I've developed the code below, but I'm bugged by the fact that the failed lines need to be known and being fixed manually.

```
public class CreateAccount {
    @PersistenceContext(unitName="filereader")
    private EntityManager em;
    private ArrayList<String> unprocessed;

    public void upload(){
        //reading the file into unprocessed
        for (String s : unprocessed) {
            this.process(s);
        }
    }

    private void process(String s){
        //Setting the entity with appropriate properties.
        //Validate the entity
        em.persist(account);
    }
}
```

This first version takes a few seconds to commit 5000 rows to database, as it seems taking advantage of caching the prepared statement. This works fine when all entities to persist are valid. However, I am concerning that even if I validate the entity, it is still possible to fail due to various unexpected reason, and when any entity throw an exception during commit, I cannot find the particular record that caused it, and all entities had been rolled back.

I had tried another approach that start a new transaction and commit for each line without using managed transaction using the following code in process(String s).

```
    for (String s : unprocessedLines) {
        try {
            em.getTransaction().begin();
            this.process(s);
            em.getTransaction().commit();
        } catch (Exception e) {
            // Any exception that a line caused can be caught here
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
```

The second version works well for logging erroneous line as exception caused by individual lines were caught and handled, but it takes over 300s to commit the same 5000 lines to database. The time it takes is not reasonable when a large file is being processed.

Is there any workaround that I could check and insert record quickly and at the same time being notified of any failed lines?

Comment: Em.flush allows you to have the persist statement issued immediately, but exceptions will still cause the entire transaction to rollback.  Using flush is probably more efficient than a transaction/line, but is less efficient than batching would be.  You might find a balance by using flush with small batches, balancing the need for speed with the need to know which exact record caused the issue if it cannot be determined from the Exception.

Answer (score 0):

Well this is more likely a guess, but why don't you try to keep the transaction and commiting it in batch, then you'll keep the rollback exception at the same time will keep the speed:

```
try {
 em.getTransaction().begin();
 for (String s : unprocessedLines) {
            this.process(s);
    }
 em.getTransaction().commit();
} catch (RollbackException exc) { 
 // here you have your rollback reason 
} finally {
  if(em.getTransaction.isActive()) {
      em.getTransaction.rollback(); // well of course you should declare em.getTransaction as a varaible above instead of constantly invoking it as I do :-)
   }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution turned out to be a binary search, and start with a block of reasonable number, e.g. last = first + 1023 to minimize the depth of the tree.

However, note that this work only if the error is deterministic, and is worse than committing each record once if the error rate is very high.

```
private boolean batchProcess(int first, int last){
    try {
        em.getTransaction().begin();
        for (String s : unprocessedLines.size(); i++) {
            this.process(s);
        }
        em.getTransaction().commit();
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
        if(em.getTransaction.isActive()) {
            em.getTransaction.rollback();
        }
        if( first == last ){
            failedLine.add(unprocessedLines(first));
        } else {
            int mid = (first + last)/2+1
            batchProcess(first, mid-1);
            batchProcess(mid, last);
        }
    }
}
```

For container managed transaction, one may need to do the binary search out of the context of the transaction, otherwise there will be `RollbackException` because the container had already decided to rollback this transaction.